# Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gluster-heketi-storageclass" failed to create volume: see kube-controller-manager.log for details

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

My Env:
kubernetes:1.20.0
glusterfs-server-6.10-1.el7.x86_64
heketi-8.0.0-1.el7.x86_64
heketi-client-8.0.0-1.el7.x86_64

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gluster-heketi-storageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
  resturl: "http://1xxxxxxx:18080"
  restauthenabled: "true"
  restuser: "admin"
  secretName: "heketi-secret"
  secretNamespace: "default"
  #volumetype: "none"
  volumetype: "replicate:3"
  clusterid: "60d0c41c0b232906f90b528fbb58400a"
```

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-vol-pvc02
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: gluster-heketi-storageclass
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

kubectl describe pvc glusterfs-vol-pvc02

```
 Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gluster-heketi-storageclass": failed to create volume: failed to create volume: see kube-controller-manager.log for details
```

Comment: So what was in `kube-controller-manager.log`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have this problem too. Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Connectivity between glusterfs nodes has been broken. Run

```
gluster peer status
```

command and check the /etc/hosts file **on all glusterfs nodes**. In my case, the hosts file lacked the necessary information and not all nodes could communicate with each other.

Comment: I only have one gluster, Numbers of peers is 0.